# angular2+: Service variable not updated in component

Tags: angular, components, angular-services, angular-components

I'm trying to use a service variable in component but when service function is call that updated variable not change in component

here is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const API_URL = environment.apiUrls.coreServiceUrl;

@Injectable()
export class LoadingBarService {
  showspinner = {isStart : false};
  start() {
    this.showspinner.isStart = true;
    console.log(this.showspinner);
    console.log('start');
  }
  complete() {
    this.showspinner.isStart = false;
    console.log('complete');
  }
}
```

I want to use showspinner in my component here is my component code

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingBarService } from './../../services/pageloader/spinner';

@Component({
  selector: 'spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit {
  showspinner;
  public constructor(private loadingBarService: LoadingBarService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.showspinner = this.loadingBarService.showspinner;
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngIf="showspinner.isStart" class="loading-icon"></div>{{showspinner | json}}
```

But this `showspinner.isStart` variable not updated real time.

Comment: When do you change the value of showSpinner.isStart?

Comment: I'm using a HttpInterceptor when http request is call  then `start()` is call

Comment: Yes, But you are only settings the value in ngOnInit... you must update the value when you do that http request. I am referring to the variable this.showSpinner, you never update it

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting the value on ngOnInit.. so the variable this.showSpinner will never change.

One solution is to bind directly the value from the service... not really elegant, but would work in most cases. Would not work if change detection skips this component.

```
<div *ngIf="loadingBarService.showspinner" class="loading-icon"></div>{{showspinner | json}}
```

The **Second** solution and **RECOMMENDED** would be nearly the same but using a BehaivourSubject. With this approach, you will be reactive, and if you are doing your actions inside the zone the spinner will ALWAYS be shown thanks to async pipe and the implicit markForCheck call.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingBarService {
   private showspinner = new BehaviorSubject(false);
   public isShowingSpinner$;
   constructor() {
       this.isShowingSpinner$ = this.showspinner.asObservable();
   }
   start() {
      this.showspinner.next(true);
      console.log(this.showspinner);
      console.log('start');
   }
   complete() {
      this.showspinner.next(false);
      console.log('complete');
   }
}
```

And In your html subscribe to it using async pipe, so you ensure markForCheck is called and is cleaner too.

```
<div *ngIf="loadingBarService.isShowingSpinner$ | async" class="loading-icon"></div>{{showspinner | json}}
```

Hope this helsp.

Comment: which one, the second solution? I had an error on the code, I have edited it @NIKHILRANE

Comment: Sorry for the changes, but now has to work. Last one solution was wrong because the function was fired every change detection run. Now is better @NIKHILRANE

Comment: Not working for me . when I'm call `start()` service variable updated but component variable not updated

Comment: You don't have a variable now... just an observable. You are running this aciton inside the zone? If yes, is almost impossible this solution is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162158/discussion-between-llorenc-pujol-ferriol-and-nikhil-rane).